# Open Server игнорирует изменения в файлах

Tags: php, html, css, openserver

Привет!У меня есть сайт на ворд пресс который я поставил на опен сервер, но я ввожу изменения в файлик Css а OpenServer меня игнорирует.

Увеличил шрифт до 30px и добавил новый
[image: Увеличил шрифт до 30px и добавил новый]

А вот это получаю когда смотрю в браузере
[image: А вот это получаю когда смотрю в браузере]

Я обновлял страничку,чистил куки,перезагружал комп,перезагружал опен сервер но ничего не помогло.

Comment: Css?Только что)

Comment: А где посмотреть response headers date?

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov, у вас либо сервер кэширует статику, либо браузер, отключите кэширование.

Answer (score 1):

Тут дело не в кешировании. Смотрите внимательно: вам браузер пишет, что стиль для h3 он взял из 136 строки style.css. Вы же проводите свои изменения в строке 8299 того же файла.

По идее, должно работать, и ваши стили в строке 8299 должны перекрывать стили из строки 136. Но не работает.

Скорее всего, выше ваших изменений в файле style.css синтаксическая ошибка, после чего весь остаток файла игнорируется браузером.